# Upper bound of set

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, upper-lower-bounds

Is it necessary only least upper bound may or may not belongs to the set and not any other upper bound????
Does always upper bound belongs to outside of the set ??

Comment: Play with symbols $($, $[$, $)$ and $]$ denoting the boundary of the interval $a,b$.

Comment: If it neither belongs to that specific set nor belongs outside the set then simply that least upper bound doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

If $S$ is a set and $a$ is an upper bound for $S$, but not the least upper bound, then there exists a smaller upper bound $a'$. So for every $x\in S$, we have $x\le a'<a$ and cannot have $a\in S$.